# Is this sentence “derogatory”?

Tags: offensive-language

Is this sentence “derogatory”?

> He just gave me the biggest fuck you of my career.

Intuitively it doesn't seem to rise to the level of derogatory; merely the use of a vulgar idiom.  But what words would successfully counter the argument that it is a derogatory statement?

Comment: I would say it's somewhere in-between. On the one hand, it doesn't directly insult you, but on the other hand it does say that you suck.

Answer (score 5):

The sentence itself merely reports the situation, so it's a case of a *use–mention distinction*. You are mentioning an expression (or metaphor) someone else used. It would be normal to make the distinction clear by either using quotes or italics:

> - He just gave me the biggest "fuck you" of my career.
> - He just gave me the biggest *fuck you* of my career.

...depending on whether "Fuck you" was actually **said** or it's a metaphor for what was **done**.

I agree that the sentence is vulgar. But it may be reporting a derogatory or insulting [and vulgar] remark.

Comment: I tend to think that 'fuck-you' should be hyphenated since it is a composite noun, not an imperative verb and object.

Comment: The sentence is vulgar but not inherently derogatory.

Answer (score 2):

If you said the sentence to someone concerning  third party's action, you would not necessarily be making a derogatory comment about either the listener or the third party.

It would indicate that you are not entirely pleased with the third party's actions.